# How do I install roofing material on a roof with a ridge vent?

Tags: roof, roofing

I am helping a friend repair his roof; his roof has a roof vent at the peak of the roof.  I've done a few roofs, but never with a roof vent.  So any help in how you roof with a roof vent?  I assume there's no roof cap underneath, since it vents the attic...  Any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: Check out [this blog post](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/resuscitating-the-roof-providing-adequate-roof-ventilation/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to remove the ridge vent so you can shingle up to the cut opening, and under where the ridge vent attaches.  If you can salvage it great, but otherwise, install a new ridge vent. Do not try to mickey mouse your last row of shingles under it to avoid taking it off. You WILL be sorry the first time it rains.

Comment: Yes I figured, we're going to do it right.  Thanks.